# How to programmatically start and run a server with a web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, server

I am using Eclipse Luna IDE. Is there any way by which I can initiate the start of a server programmatically (i.e, on press of particular keys - for example `ctrl+r`). Also, I want to deploy a web project on this server automatically. That is without having the need to select the project and then selecting 'run on server'.  
I have gone through [this](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html) article, but I could not run the example because of some errors.
 1. `The hierarchy of the type TomcatPlugin is inconsistent`    - TomcatPlugin (name of a class) extends AbstractUIPlugin Interface. I know the reason for this error, it needs some jar but I could not found the appropriate jar. 
2. `The constructor Object(IPluginDescriptor) is undefined.`
3. `The method getDescriptor() is undefined for the type TomcatPlugin.`
Also, that article doesn't include the deploying of web application part inside the launched server.  
 How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming you are trying to start a Tomcat Web server, could you please add the errors you got while starting it ?

Comment: for basic web applications deployment is going to be automatic, you won't even have to restart the server. As soon as you save your changes, the server is going to redeploy your project. You don't have to worry about that. If you make significant changes, like interface realizations, then you will most probably have ot restart your server as well.

Comment: @DhanushGopinath: I have added the errors that I got.